# Django ManyToManyField optimal way to access the related data

Tags: python, django, orm, relational-database

I have two following django models with ManyToManyField relation

**Book Model**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('authors.Author')
```

**Author Model**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Let's say I'm getting all the books by running the query

```
books = Book.objects.filter(name="some value").prefect_related('authors')
```

What's the optimized way to get all the authors related to the above resulted books.

what I'm trying now is

```
authors = [] 
for book in books:
    for author in book.authors.all():
        authors.append(author.id)
authors = Author.objects.filter(id__in=authors).distinct()
```

But this looks very expensive. What would be the optimal way to get the related authors set.

Answer (score 2):

Even with your expensive method, there's no need to query the authors again at the end: inside each inner loop, `author` is already an Author instance, so you could just have appended that to your list rather than the ID.

But you're right, there is a much cheaper way to do it, and that is to use the relationship directly in the query. As always, if you want Authors, you should start with Authors and traverse to Books:

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(book__in=Book.authors.all())
```

which will translate to a single query with a subquery.

This might be even cheaper:

```
authors = Author.objects.exclude(book=None)
```

since that is a simple JOIN, and it should give you the same results in this case.

Comment: Isn't it book_set instead of the way you use it as a field

Comment: No, in a lookup you always use the lower-case name of the field whether it is forward or backward.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the authors, you can simply query on `book__name`:

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(book__name="some value")
```

You can use `.prefetch_related('book')` to prefetch the books. If you really need a flat list of both books and authors, you can skip `prefetch_related` and do this:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(name="some value")
authors = Author.objects.filter(book__in=books)
```